# How to achieve zoom action in maps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using react-native-maps and I want to zoom to a specific lat lon location when i init my maps in my react native project. I heard that it is called as camera zoom but couldn't find anything that could help me with this problem.

Any lead would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `minZoomLevel` to zoom the map to my location when map is initialized. Below is the code:

```
this.state = {
          region: {
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          },
<MapView
      provider={ PROVIDER_GOOGLE }
      style={ styles.map }
      initialRegion={this.state.region}
      onPress={this.onMapPress}
      minZoomLevel={10}  //to zoom map to my location
      />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and also sorry for not closing this question. I have used `this.map.animateToRegion()` for zooming. Anyways thanks for responding.